# Paging concept using scrollviewer in wp

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new to wp7. I want to add three images to my page. But not on a single page. It should be on three pages. When i move the image, at that time, the image is changed and i am on the secong page keeping my header and footer fixed.

So how to add three image in one page?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use scroll-viewer?

1) Try using a pivot control without any pivot headers. Add your images to three different pivot items. In pivot the header and footer you specify will remain fixed, only the content will change.

2) Also you can create a single page. Add three images to a list. Bind it to your image control. On flick gesture, change the image URL hence changing the image being displayed but keeping every thing else constant.

I gave you two approaches, try using any one of them which suits you the best. For further information try studying pivots and flick gestures.

Comment: Aggrawal:Thanks for giving me advice and pivot is not sutable for me but gesture is good.but i dont know how to use On flick gesture.Please give me some code how to use gesture

Comment: you can learn about estures form here: http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API